# Does this recursion problem have a typo?

Tags: number-theory, induction, recursion

Just wondering how to cast this sentence into the actual intention — #8

[image]

Comment: do you understand that $(a,b)$ probably denotes $\gcd(a,b)$ ?

Comment: Ahh, I think it means GCD = 1

Comment: Just another reason for me to hate  that notation lol. But I agree with J.W., that seems to make the most sense. $(a_2,a_1) = (1,1) = 1$, and $(a_3,a_2) = (4,1) = 1$ and $(a_4,a_3) = (13,4) = 1$, and so on, so it seems like that is the intention here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $(a_n,a_{n+1})=1$ can mean that the [greatest common divisor](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatestCommonDivisor.html) of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is $1$;

i.e., $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ are relatively prime.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. This is common notation for *greatest common divisor*. That is, $(a,b) = 1$ means that $a$ and $b$ only share $1$ as a divisor.

Comment: "No, it does not": what exactly are you disagreeing with?

Comment: @NickD The title question, "Does this recursion problem have a typo?", probably.

Comment: Ah, yes - that makes sense. Thanks!